# Android ffmpeg How to add watermark on video file

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I am trying to add watermark on video file using FFmpegFrameFilter but watermark is not adding on output video. also output video not correct getting only one second video where video length is 8 seconds. please help me. here my code

```
  class FinishWaterMarkTask extends ProgressDialogTask<Void, Integer, Void> {


    private FFmpegFrameGrabber VIDEO_GRABBER;
    private FFmpegFrameRecorder videoRecorder;
    private FFmpegFrameFilter filter;


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


        Frame tempVideoFrame;
        try {
            VIDEO_GRABBER.start();
            String OutputPath = path + outputVideo;
            initVideoRecorder(OutputPath);
            filter.start();
            while (VIDEO_GRABBER.grab() != null) {
                tempVideoFrame = VIDEO_GRABBER.grabImage();
                if (tempVideoFrame != null) {
                    filter.push(tempVideoFrame);
                    tempVideoFrame = filter.pull();
                    videoRecorder.record(tempVideoFrame);
                }
            }
            videoRecorder.stop();
            filter.stop();
            videoRecorder.release();
            VIDEO_GRABBER.stop();
            VIDEO_GRABBER.release();
        } catch (FrameGrabber.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FrameFilter.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void initVideoRecorder(String path) {
        try {
 VIDEO_GRABBER = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(mVideo.getAbsolutePath());
            String imgPath = audioPath + "jodelicon.png";
            filter = new FFmpegFrameFilter("movie=" + imgPath + " [logo];[in][logo]overlay=0:0:1:format=rgb [out]", VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageWidth(), VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageHeight());
            videoRecorder = FFmpegFrameRecorder.createDefault(path, VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageWidth(), VIDEO_GRABBER.getImageHeight());
            videoRecorder.setAudioChannels(VIDEO_GRABBER.getAudioChannels());
            videoRecorder.setFrameRate(VIDEO_GRABBER.getFrameRate());

            videoRecorder.start();
        } catch (FrameRecorder.Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: This is the command i'm using for this....may help you...ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i path+watermark.png -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" video.mp4

Comment: @kulvinder i am using this library. compile group: 'org.bytedeco', name: 'javacv', version: '1.3'. can you please tell me how can i execute this command briefly

Comment: okey let me try to explain: follow this file https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/hiteshsondhi88/sampleffmpeg/Home.java      there is  method in this class execFFmpegBinary(string[] command)   just call this method by passing String command=""ffmpeg", "-i", "video.mp4", "-i", "path+watermark.png", "-filter_complex", "overlay=10:10", "video.mp4"";  ...hope it will help you lot

Comment: i know about writingMinds ffmpeg library but i can't use both library in project. getting unstisfied link error. in or.bytedoco gradle there is no way to execute comands. I can only use FFmpegFrameFilter for add watermark on video

Comment: Hi @hitesh, Have you found any solution?